# Getting Error while Inserting the Query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

Please help me to find the error in the below statements where i am getting error in only from code.

Create table Statement

```
cmmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Users([User_ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, UserName Text(50), UserPwdText(200), [IsActive] YesNo, [ModBy] Long REFERENCES Users (User_ID), [ModDate] Date)";
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In the database table is created successfully.
Here I am Inserting values through code.

```
cmmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Users ([UserName], [UserPwd], [IsActive], [ModBy],
           [ModDate])VALUES('Admin','kov1ozyKAjas8awoej3oijhrqoi6q=', 'true', '1', 
           'Datetime.Now.Date')";
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The exception is

`Data type mismatch in criteria expression`

Comment: Kindly show the Table with its variables

Comment: you have 2 parentheses after VALUES

Comment: @Nimesh What is there to confuse ? I think actual problem is with the `IsActive` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

The recommended way is to use parameters. Using a parameterized query not only steps around SQL injection issues, but solves SQL Server date localization issues as well.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Users ([UserName], [UserPwd], [IsActive], [ModBy], [ModDate])VALUES('Admin','kov1ozyKAjas8awoej3oijhrqoi6q=', 'true', '1', @dateValue)");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateValue", DateTime.Now.Date);
.......
// do same for the other.
```

You have 2 parentheses after VALUES in your code

Check this :

```
string format = "yyyy-mm-dd"; //or with date yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
cmmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO Users ([UserName], [UserPwd], [IsActive], [ModBy], [ModDate])VALUES('Admin','kov1ozyKAjas8awoej3oijhrqoi6q=', 'true', '1', '{0}')", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format));
```

Also you should use parameters.

Comment: I tried your code. got this exceotion `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Comment: what is the type of IsActive? if is bit you should insert 1 or 0, not "true" as string.

Comment: Yes , but In Ms Access database its datatype is YesNo".

Comment: Thank you for your time for my small question.

Answer (score 5):

First of all check for the DataTypes of each Fields. And make sure that you have used appropriate DataTypes as per the tables.  and if everythings ok then just try below query.

```
cmmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Users ([UserName], [UserPwd], [IsActive], 
            [ModBy],[ModDate])VALUES('Admin','kov1ozyKAjas8awoej3oijhrqoi6q=',
            'true', '1', 'Datetime.Now.Date')";
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two errors in your query first is double bracket and second one is `DateTime.Now.Date`. it is a .Net feature that you cannot execute it in string. And here you don't need to add @ at the beginning of the string. Also change `'True' to Yes`

try this

```
cmmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users ([UserName], [UserPwd], [IsActive], 
            [ModBy],[ModDate])VALUES('Admin','kov1ozyKAjas8awoej3oijhrqoi6q=',
            Yes, '1', Date())";
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: basicaly your Yes/No field stores bit (0/1) value in the database. So, you can use both Yes/No and 0/1 in your query.

Comment: Yes It also worked. What should I do now, I clicked @Mihai Hantea as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
cmmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Users ([UserName], [UserPwd], [IsActive], [ModBy], [ModDate])VALUES('Admin','kov1ozyKAjas8awoej3oijhrqoi6q=', 'true', '1', 'Datetime.Now.Date')";
```

One parenthesis, not two.

Comment: I tried your code, but got error `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Comment: That would be due to you using `DateTime.Now.Date`, which means nothing to Access. Try `GETDATE()` or something.

Answer (score 2):

With `DateTime.Now.Date`, are u trying to get the date?

Try this:

```
cmmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Users ([UserName], [UserPwd], [IsActive], [ModBy], [ModDate]) VALUES ('Admin', 'kov1ozyKAjas8awoej3oijhrqoi6q=', 'true', '1', Datetime.Now.Date)";
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, The datetime is a string if you put inside of the double quote or single quote, So you need the query look like.

```
cmmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Users ([UserName], [UserPwd], [IsActive], 
            [ModBy],[ModDate])VALUES('Admin','kov1ozyKAjas8awoej3oijhrqoi6q=',
            'true', '1', '" + DateTime.Now.Date + "')";
                    cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I hopes my query is does not return any errors.